# Using hibernate in real time

Tags: hibernate, real-time, batch-processing, production

Now i have finished my database model using hibernate and java `POJO` classes. Now I want to use my database in real time.

I saw any articles saying that we should not count on `hibernate.bm2ddl.update` in production and we should use manual batches.

- what should i do now?
- what are these batches?
- what should i do regarding hibernate after i finish my model to start using it in real time?

I alreay tried update an validate but it take tie wen talking to the databae

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what are these batches?

These are basically some SQL scripts containing DDL or DML instructions to update the database in a safe manner. E.g. how would you go about adding a column to a table on production? You can't simply drop table and create it from scratch with an extra column. You need to have something like :
`ALTER TABLE tab ADD COLUMN new_col int`

> what should i do regarding hibernate after i finish my model to start
>   using it in real time?

Remove `hibernate.bm2ddl.update` from your production configuration and you should be all good.

I would recommend not using this option for development as well to force developers to create needed scripts so that they can later be used to update production database.

Comment: Thanks so much for your information i will count on it.